# Redirect complete website to https with www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

A classic question about redirecting my complete website to https with www and without trailing slash and valid when client is behind a proxy-server or not. I find 101 partial solutions but they are so confusing for me because the comments on each proposed solution always indicate conditions where the redirect could not function. I would be very pleased with a complete solution

I recently bought a SSL certificate for my domain example.com. According to my information the SSL certificate is only valid for example.com and not for www.example.com but I'm not completely sure.

I want a permanent redirect to https://www. in all cases without a trailing slash and valid behind proxy-server or not:

1. http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
2. http://www.example.com/ to https://www.example.com
3. http://example.com to https://www.example.com
4. http://example.com/ to https://www.example.com
5. http://www.example.com/any-url to https://www.example.com/any-url
6. http://www.example.com/any-url/ to https://www.example.com/any-url
7. http://example.com/any-url to https://www.example.com/any-url
8. http://example.com/any-url/ to https://www.example.com/any-url

At this moment I only have the redirect from non www to www for my former http:// website in my htaccess file (which was correctly functioning for the website without https:// ):

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# redirect rules first
# Without www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What do I have to add or what would be the replacing code?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Regards,
Sabine

....

I received no suggestions yet after the first day, so I will probably implement and test the following code this evenin, although I think it is not complete:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Sabine

Comment: First, you need to know if your new SSL includes www. If it doesn't nothing you do to redirect will work correctly. It will display a warning page until you have a valid cert for www also. Then we can help with the rules.

Comment: Hello, I just received confirmation from my webhosting company that my SSL certification is valid for both domain.com and www.domain.com. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this configuration in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```